# Error message while opening exported excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm exporting my grid to excel with a normal onRequestStart function in JS (here is the function)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            function onRequestStart(sender, args) {
                if (args.get_eventTarget().indexOf("ExportToExcelButton") >= 0 ||
                 args.get_eventTarget().indexOf("ExportToWordButton") >= 0 ||
                 args.get_eventTarget().indexOf("ExportToCsvButton") >= 0) {
                    args.set_enableAjax(false);
                }
            }
</script>
```

then I'm calling on Grid_ItemCommand  an checking if it is a excel export word or csv then im calling my method doExport()

```
 private void doExport()
        {
            this.UserGrid.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = true;
            this.UserGrid.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = true;
            this.UserGrid.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = true;
            this.UserGrid.ExportSettings.FileName = String.Format("YearReport_{0}_{1}", this.selectedYear, this.rcbDepartments.SelectedValue);
        }
```

And everything is working perfectly so far , but after finish downloading the file and opening in excel a strange  > "Warring Message" arrived is there a solution how to disable this message ?  [image]

Thanks for help and fast answer

PS:If you need something more feel free to ask

Comment: Sorry, comment removed, I hope you find the help you need (hint save as XLSX instead of XLS) :)

Comment: @JMK Thanks same here where I'm saying that I'm saving the file as xls ?

Comment: In your screenshot, @ZorleQ gave the same answer before I wrote the comment by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that  this grid component is  exporting it to html and just add a xlsx tag or what ever so excel in 2010 has this new  mechanism  that is protecting excel to open unknown files I think for my self there is no solution for that problem ..

Comment: some one agree with that ?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/948615/error-opening-file-the-file-format-differs-from-the-format-that-the-fi

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the mismatch between the actual file type and the extension because you are exporting the data as CSV yet you are telling Excel that it's an XLS file. This is a normal Excel warning.

If you want to disable this, just make sure that the file exported has the "csv" extension instead.

Comment: sry but where did you saw that can you please explain me that = ?

Comment: Didn't you say this: "then I'm calling on Grid_ItemCommand an checking if it is a excel export word or **CSV** then im calling my method doExport()"?

Comment: yee and so it sees that the file is excel not csv

Comment: @Mingebag did you actually read what you posted? You posted a picture that shows that you are exporting the file as **XLS** (it has the full file name in there) and yet you say that you are exporting it as **CSV**...

Comment: @Mingebag I gave you a solution already: When you export the file, name it `File_2013_Or_Whatever.CSV` and the problem will go away.

Comment: I'm sry but where can I say that i want to export this file as csv

Comment: I would imagine with this line: `this.UserGrid.ExportSettings.FileName = String.Format("YearReport_{0}_{1}", this.selectedYear, this.rcbDepartments.SelectedValue=="XLS"?"CSV":this.rcbDepartments.SelectedValue);` Or simply change the Values in the DropDown list to be "CSV" and "DOC" (for Word)

Comment: @Icarus is right here, the file is CSV not XLSX, and rcbDepartments is probably a dropdown on your webform, so find the dropdown and see what values it contains, and what value is selected when you click the button.

Comment: @Icarus If I add as you sad just the .CSV to the file name i have the same error with a new name

Answer (score 2):

Save the export file as a ".xlsx" file. This happens all the time when you save an Office 2003 style as .xlsx or the other way around.

**Edit**

Or as mentioned in the other answer, ".csv". The same concept applies.

Excel detects that the file content doesn't match given extension, hence the error.

Comment: Nicely done @JMK, I've never used the UserGrid before, but I've seen this error many time in other tools which are exporting to Excel. For some reason they devs ALWAYS mess up this format.

Comment: @JMK tried something like that (this.UserGrid.ExportSettings.FileName = String.Format("YearReport_{0}_{1}", this.selectedYear, this.rcbDepartments.SelectedValue=="XLS"?"CSV":this.rcbDepartments.SelectedValue‌​);) but somehow its notworking can you please proived me the solution ?

Comment: Try appending extension directly to the file name. Maybe that will force it. (Try with both, CVS and XLSX)

`this.UserGrid.ExportSettings.FileName = String.Format("YearReport_{0}_{1}.XLSX", this.selectedYear, this.rcbDepartments.SelectedValue);`

Comment: no changes just got the same message whit a different name YearReport_2013_.XLSX.xls

Comment: Seems like the component is using its default extension. Unless you find an option, which allows to override that, the only thing you have left to do is what @MCraft said - just append ".xlsx" once the file has been exported.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs because of creating the Excel file using `Mime Type` not by `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`,

**Cause of this Error :**

```
    The alert is a new security feature in Excel 2007 called Extension Hardening, which 
ensures that the file content being opened matches the extension type specified in the 
shell command that is attempting to open the file. Because the MIME types listed above are 
associated with the .XLS extension, the file must be in XLS (BIFF8) file format to open 
without this warning prompt.  If the file type is a different format (such as HTML, XML, 
CSV, etc.) the prompt is expected since the file content is different that the extension 
or MIME type. The alert is first seen when opening the file from a URL site directly.  If 
you cancel the alert, the open will fail, but then IE will attempt to download the file 
and open again using a different shell command. Depending on what the file contents is and 
what extension IE gives the file it downloads, you may see the second open attempt 
succeed, or you may see the prompt again but with a different filename in the alert dialog.

    The alert prompt is "by design", but the interaction of the cancel action and IE's 
attempt to open the file again is a known problem under investigation for a future fix.
```

**Explanation Source :** http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/03/11/excel-2007-extension-warning.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on a programmatic way of doing this with c#. Outside of c# if you're just trying to open the file from your file system on windows you can modify the registry to ignore it.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/948615/error-opening-file-the-file-format-differs-from-the-format-that-the-fi

I'll follow up with my programmatic solution, if I get it.